# Android Emulator error issue

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have tried my best to solve it using the solutions available here but nothing has worked so far.
Kindly help me to resolve this error.
Emulator crashes...

```
init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsStringARB!
emulator: WARNING: Crash service did not start
emulator: WARNING: encryption is off
emulator: WARNING: Not all modern X86 virtualization features supported, which introduces problems with slowdown when running Android on  multicore vCPUs. Setting AVD to run with 1 vCPU core only.
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x20000000
path C:\Users\Abid\.android\avd\Nexus_5X_API_23.avd\system.img.qcow2
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
emulator: WARNING: The -scale flag is obsolete and will be ignored.
```

Comment: you can use genymotion if android studio emulator is not working

Answer (score 0):

you can use genymotion as a emulator. its provide all the api versions, u can download it for free of cost.
link for downloading the genymotion emulator : https://www.genymotion.com/
For using google play store in it , we need to install some additional things to it

Comment: I have tried to run genymotion but it says that graphic driver should be updated. When i tried to update the driver online, it says that driver is already updated. So this solution is not working

Comment: some case we need to manually enable virtualization option in BIOS. follow below link for enable virtualization link: http://bce.berkeley.edu/enabling-virtualization-in-your-pc-bios.html

Answer (score 0):

I think your computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology or it is not enabled in BIOS.

Create a new emulator and choose `arm` instead of `x86/x64`.
ARM images which will not need hardware virtualization

Create Virtual Device->Select hardware->System image(go to other images tab)->Select one.

Comment: I have tried this solution but it didn't worked. I have enabled virtualization in BIOS, created a new emulator as you told but still same error.

Comment: download image that is not x86..I think you need to download arm file

Comment: delete the .android file from here C:\Users\Abid\ and create emulator